# Adventure 80s movie: Guy rescues his fiance from a teleporting castle

Tags: identify-this-movie

This is a tough one, as I have very limited info. It appears to be a forgotten adventure film from around the 80's.

- Guy's fiance/loved one is kidnapped by an evil wizard (not Tom Cruise/Legend!).
- Wizard tells the guy that he has to find a teleporting/disappearing castle that only appears once at a specific point in time.
- Guy goes on to rescue her with a party of other people/friends.
- On their journey, one of the companions comes across 'Death', and it turns out that friend was in love with Death a long time ago. The friend asks Death to help them on their journey.
- At the end, they reach the castle (in time) flying on mythical creatures (flying unicorns or something).

Answer (score 13):

[image]

The movie is **Krull.** (1983)

The planet **Krull** is invaded by an entity known as the "Beast" and his army. Prince Colwyn and Princess Lyssa plan to marry in the hope that their combined forces can defeat the Beast. *The Beast’s army attacks the wedding before it is finished and kidnaps the princess*, leaving Colwyn and the entire kingdom for dead.

Prince Colwyn is *found and nursed by Ynyr, the Old One*. Ynyr tells him the Beast can be defeated with the "Glaive", a five-pointed throwing weapon. Colwyn sets out to track down the prison where the Lyssa is being held, the *Black Fortress, which teleports to a new location every day at sunrise.* *As they travel, Colwyn and Inyr are joined by magician Ergo, a band of nine thieves, and a cyclops.*

They travel to find a wizard who can tell them where the castle will be the next day but he is defeated magically by the Beast before he can.

In a last ditch attempt to find the fortress, Ynyr leaves the group to journey to *the "Widow of the Web", an enchantress who loved him long ago and was exiled* to the lair of the Crystal Spider for murdering their only child. The Widow reveals where the Black Fortress will be at sunrise. She also gives Ynyr the sand from the enchanted hourglass that kept the Crystal Spider from attacking her and will keep a badly injured Ynyr alive on his journey back to the group. As the Crystal Spider attacks the Widow, Ynyr flees the web and returns to the group to reveal the location of the Black Fortress, as he loses the last of the sand and expires.

The group capture and *ride mystical flying Fire Mares* (which look like Clydesdale stallions with fiery hooves) to reach the Black Fortress before it teleports again, and enter the castle before it disappears. Colwyn attacks, but does not kill, the Beast with the Glaive, losing the Glaive forever. They royal couple quickly complete the wedding, releasing the their linked power, and they defeat the Beast with fire.

Condensed from: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_%28film%29)

Comment: Exactly what I thought just from the question title.

Comment: Assuming this is correct (which I'm sure it is), the "companion who was in love with death" is probably Ynyr who had a romance with the Widow of the Web (who is probably the 'death' character) long before the events of the movie. The "flying unicorns" are probably the Fire Mares, who are the only creatures who can run fast enough to make it to the Black Fortress in time - they run so fast that flames spring from their hooves.

Comment: *Krull* is not forgotten… But it’s utterly forgettable…